# Запись таблицы в текстовый файл

Tags: c#, mysql

Пытаюсь записать таблицу в текстовый файл, но запись происходит только для первой  строки, а остальная часть таблицы не записывается. Как исправить код, чтобы писалась вся таблица? Главное в консоль выводится вся таблица верно.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // строка подключения к БД
        string connStr = "server = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password =; database = blacklist999";
        // создаём объект для подключения к БД
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        // устанавливаем соединение с БД
        conn.Open();
        // запрос
        string sql = "SELECT steamID, type, why FROM toxics";
        // объект для выполнения SQL-запроса
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        // объект для чтения ответа сервера
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        // читаем результат
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // элементы массива [] - это значения столбцов из запроса SELECT
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() + "|" + reader[1].ToString() + "@" + reader[2].ToString());
        }

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\1.txt");
        sw.Write(reader[0].ToString() + "|" + reader[1].ToString() + "@" + reader[2].ToString());
        sw.Close();

        reader.Close(); // закрываем reader
        // закрываем соединение с БД
        conn.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Если поместить в sw.Write в while (reader.Read()) ничего не меняется :(

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // строка подключения к БД
        string connStr = "server = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password =; database = blacklist999";
        // создаём объект для подключения к БД
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        // устанавливаем соединение с БД
        conn.Open();
        // запрос
        string sql = "SELECT steamID, type, why FROM toxics";
        // объект для выполнения SQL-запроса
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        // объект для чтения ответа сервера
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        // читаем результат
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // элементы массива [] - это значения столбцов из запроса SELECT
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() + "|" + reader[1].ToString() + "@" + reader[2].ToString());
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\1.txt");
            sw.Write(reader[0].ToString() + "|" + reader[1].ToString() + "@" + reader[2].ToString());
            sw.Close();
        }

        reader.Close(); // закрываем reader
        // закрываем соединение с БД
        conn.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // строка подключения к БД
        string connStr = "server = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password =; database = blacklist999";

        using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT steamID, type, why FROM toxics";
            con.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\1.txt"))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() + "|" + reader[1].ToString() + "@" + reader[2].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Поместите

```
sw.Write(reader[0].ToString() + "|" + reader[1].ToString() + "@" + reader[2].ToString());
```

В цикл `while`, туда, где вы выводите в информацию о записи в консоль

Comment: Такой код работает, так же как и предыдущий. Обновил код в вопросе.

Comment: Так же пишет 1 строку, может быть прописать while для записи в файл отдельно, только не знаю как.